How to change cpp format to exe format when editing launch.json & tasks.json?
I've recently installed vscode and I'm currently struggling with debugging. I'm hitting a roadblock with this error always popping up:
"gdb failed with message: "..." not in executable format: format not recognized."
I've searched up many tutorials online but it just says i need a compiler to turn cpp into exe, but isn't vsc a compiler?
my current launch,json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.cpp",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}

tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Run tests",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gdb.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-Wall",
            "-g",
            "${workspaceFolder}/test.cpp", 
            "-o",
],
        "group": "test",
        "presentation": {
          "reveal": "always",
          "panel": "new"
        }
      }
    ]
  }


Instead of following (bad) tutorials, you could try the official guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

but isn't vsc a compiler? No, VSCode is very much not a compiler. Its an IDE with the ability to run external tools to build and debug + it has an Intellisense feature.

"program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.cpp", is wrong in your launch.json It basically says to use test.cpp as the executable. This line should have been: "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",

Your tasks.json is missing this: "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",  after the "-o",  and before the ],

I wouldn't even call VS Code an IDE. There's nothing Integrated about the completely optional development environments. It's an extensible text editor like vim, emacs et. al.

This line "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.cpp", is wrong, it should be invoking an executable and not your source code. Your launch.json also never specifies a build task. Don't create these from scratch. Let VS Code do it for you, then edit the necessary bits as needed. The official documentation linked above could have avoided all of this mess.

Use MinGW.
A guide is found here

This is a comment and not an answer. As such, I recommend deleting this before you receive downvotes. Please wait until you have sufficient repuatation to leave comments.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
